# Running multiple epochs in clients of federated-tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated

Is there any way in federated-tensorflow to make clients train the model for multiple epochs on their dataset? I found on the tutorials that a solution could be modifying the dataset by running dataset.repeat(NUMBER_OF_EPOCHS), but why should I modify the dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tf.data.Dataset` is the TF2 way of setting this up. It maybe useful to think about the code as modifying the "data pipeline" rather than the "dataset" itself.

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data and particularly the section https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#processing_multiple_epochs can be useful pointers.

At a high-level, the `tf.data` API sets up a stream of examples. Repeats (multiple epochs) of that stream can be configured as well.

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(5)
for x in dataset:
  print(x) # prints 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 on separate lines.

repeated_dataset = dataset.repeat(2)
for x in repeated_dataset:
  print(x) # same as above, but twice

shuffled_repeat_dataset = dataset.shuffle(
  buffer_size=5, reshuffle_each_iteration=True).repeat(2)
for x in repeated_dataset:
  print(x) # same as above, but twice, with different orderings.
```